# Sails v1 new machine-based actions and custom responses

Tags: sails.js

I'm in the middle of upgrading our API from Sails v0.12 -> v1, which was prompted by the use of self-validating machines for controller actions. After finally getting through a ton of headache replacing deprecated code, I've landed in a rough spot...

With v0.12 (rather, with the older "req, res" controller style), one could use custom response handlers across the board. I've taken advantage of this, and have request logging at the end of all our response types (with some additional sugaring of data). This was done to log all requests in the database, so we can get insights into what our production servers are doing (because they are load-balanced, having a central place to view this is a must, and this was an easy route to take).

So now, my problem is moving forward with "Actions2" machine-style actions. How does one use these custom response types in these things? Are we being forced to repeat ourselves in our exists? I can't find any good documentation to help guide this process, nor can I find a consistent way to "hook" into the end of a response using machines as actions. I can't find any documentation on what kind of options machines can give to Sails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Nelson yes, I understand that, but at the time, that isn't what I wanted at all. I wanted all of the benefits of Actions2.

EDIT: While the original, crossed-out comment below does still work, the prefered way to use Actions2 and the custom `responses` folder paradigm, is to do something similar to the following in an Actions2 file:

```
module.exports = {
    friendlyName: 'Human-friendly name of function',

    description: 'Long description of function and what it does.',

    inputs: {
        userCommand: {
            type: 'string',
            required: true,
            description: 'Long, human-readable description of the input'
        }
    },

    exits: {
        success: {
             responseType: 'chatbotResponse'
        }
    },

    fn: async function(inputs, exits){
        // do some crazy stuff with the inputs, which has already been validated.

        return exits.success('Woot');
    }
}
```

This ultimately will route through the `responses/chatbotResponse.js`, which looks something similar to this:

```
module.exports = async function chatbotResponse(data){
    let res = this.res,
        req = this.req;

    if (!data) {
        data = 'Something didn\'t go as planned...';
    }

    // how to call a Node Machine style helper with named inputs
    await sails.helpers.finalizeRequestLog.with({req: req, res: res, body: {plainString: data}});

    return res.json(data);
};
```

ORIGINAL:

<strike>As it turns out, in the Actions2 function, you just need to add the `env` param `async function(inputs, exists, env)`. The `env` will give you access to the `req` and `res`. So, if you have custom responses, that perform special tasks (like request logging), you can just use `return await env.res.customResponse('Hurray, you made a successful call!');`</strike>